# Producing NULL Value related to AVG(field) in HAVING CLAUSE

Tags: sql, having, having-clause, aggregates

Here is my table:

[image: Related Table]

There are Multiple Salaries under 61,000.

The AVG Salary for Related table is 61K.

[image]

If I write a query:

```
SELECT `StaffID`, `Title`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `DeptID`, `Salary` 
FROM `Staff` 
WHERE `Left` < '2018-00-00' 
AND `ContractType` = 'Full time' *HAVING AVG(`Salary`) < `Salary`*;
```

It will produce one result with the Salary being 27000. The AVG Salary at 61K is not less than 27K.

If I change the comparison operator in the same query to:

```
*AVG(`Salary`) > `Salary`;*
```

No record will be produced.

Can anyone shine a light as to why?

Comment: That query is invalid to begin with and any self-respecting database should refuse to run it.

Answer (score 0):

This query is malformed:

```
SELECT StaffID, Title, FirstName, LastName, DeptID, Salary
FROM Staff
WHERE Left < '2018-00-00' AND ContractType = 'Full time'
HAVING AVG(Salary) < Salary;
```

It is an aggregation query because it has an aggregation function `AVG()`.  However, there is no `GROUP BY`, so there should be no unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.  That is, the query should generate an error.

I can only assume you are using a database that -- sadly -- allows such malformed queries.

You don't state what you want to do.  In particular, do the `where` conditions apply to the average or not.  However, one good solution uses window functions:

```
SELECT StaffID, Title, FirstName, LastName, DeptID, Salary
FROM (SELECT s.*, AVG(Salary) OVER () as avg_salary
      FROM Staff s
      WHERE Left < '2018-00-00' AND ContractType = 'Full time'
     ) s
WHERE salary > avg_salary;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub-query Worked:

```
SELECT StaffID, Title, FirstName, LastName, DeptID, Salary FROM Staff WHERE Left < '2018-00-00' 
AND ContractType = 'Full time' HAVING 'Salary' < 
(
    Select AVG(Salary) FROM Staff
);
```